# Tridion GUI not fully loading in Chrome, IE

Tags: 2011, cme

I have a client who is reporting that Tridion 2011 SP1 is not fully loading for him. The left panel loads and the ribbon fully loads, but never the center pane. In another environment, he had this problem, but only with Chrome. Now, in our Test environment, it is with Chrome and IE.

I am unable to reproduce this issue in IE9, Google Chrome 25, or FireFox. What could be the cause of this issue?

I know I could tell him to use another browser, but I'd rather understand the root cause so that I don't have to.

We have installed two new GUI extensions in this environment: a custom one and Power Tools. These GUI extensions were first in Dev and they have now been migrated to Test. The client is supposed to test the custom extension in our test environment.

Comment: He has a version of something cached in his browser on that env you don't (or vice versa.) maybe? Use fiddler and/or fiddler cap to whatch exactly what is going on in terms of browser requests and compare the requests your browser makes with his.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood. I thought you were talking about this behaviour: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/223/during-gui-extension-development-what-are-the-likely-causes-of-a-blank-user-int have deleted my answer

Comment: It is probably also worth having a look in developer tools finding out if there are any JS errors occurring.

Answer (score 11):

If the CME is working OK for everyone else, and this is an isolated issue that relates to just one or two users, then it sounds like this could be down to the user's browser settings or something on their computer causing the problem.

Can you check that the user in question has got their web browser configured correctly to use the CME? The documentation which details the correct settings is available here:

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011/task_43B1609144D94562A394BB51FAC884B9 ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

Also, for Internet Explorer, we have come across a number of computers where the "Enable native XMLHTTP support" option is not checked.  With this disabled, we have experienced similar issues to what you are describing. This option is under Tools > Internet Options> Advanced, and is under the security heading towards the bottom. It would be worth checking that this is enabled too.

Also make sure that the user has cleared their browser cache.

Answer (score 9):

Have them empty their browser cache.   After installing GUI Extensions it is necessary.  My guess is that they loaded the GUI previously using their favorite browser and now when using the same browser with the GUI extensions it fails.  When using a virgin browser it succeeds.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to this, SDL wrote a great document titled 'Debugging the SDL Tridion CME' - it's available [online here](https://sdltridionworld.com/images/SDLWCMS_Debugging%20the%20Tridion%202011%20CME_tcm89-20439.pdf)

Section 7.3 contains information on how to debug the CME using Chrome. - hope this helps :)