# Possible reasons for CME not loading

Tags: 2013, cme

I installed a fresh patch of msi with validated code in my server. However, the CME does not load and just freezes as below. Where do I start looking for the error?

[image: CME not loading]

Comment: Share more information - What msi/code and where?

Comment: Also, is there any error in the notification area or in the even log?

Comment: Do you see this problem in all browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [During GUI Extension development, what are the likely causes of a blank user interface with a grey bar](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/223/during-gui-extension-development-what-are-the-likely-causes-of-a-blank-user-int/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open firebug or some sort of debug tool.

You'll find a call that looks more or less like this: `http://servername/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.11_.aspx?mode=js` (in your case that v6.1... should probably be v7.0...., since you are on 2013 GA).

Copy that URL and load it in the browser, it should show you a .NET error trace that will help you identify what failed. The most typical cause is that an extension is mapped to a file location that doesn't exist.

Comment: sounds like you know something new and cool... blog post?

Comment: http://www.curlette.com/?p=913

Answer (score 4):

I personally call that one the 'white screen of death' - this one 99% of the time fails when there is a javascript error.

You can use chrome developer tools to see what's causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

There are very good resources on SDL Live Content site for UI Troubleshooting, check below link.

[Troubleshooting browser-based user interfaces](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-7B56CE7F-E978-4E84-878B-09C1D81734FD) (Login Required)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the URL to the local intranet also fix this "White screen of death" in some cases