# JS file is not loading From editor.config(Load Jquery js files eg(Jquery UI)) for GUI Extensions

Tags: 2011, 2013, cme, gui-extensions, 2013-sp1

Hi i am  working on gui extension want to add some jquery libraries but it is not loading in the cme ,CME got Crashed,i am using jquery and jqery ui js

i have this config

```
 <cfg:group name="Extension.Counter" merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.CommandGroupProcessor" merge="always">
        <cfg:fileset>
         <cfg:file type="style">/Extrensions/Editors/jquery-ui.structure.css</cfg:file> 
         <cfg:file type="style">/Extrensions/Editors/jquery-ui.theme.css</cfg:file> 
         <cfg:file type="style">/Extrensions/Editors/jquery-ui.css</cfg:file> 
         <cfg:file type="script">/Extrensions/Editors/jquery-ui.js</cfg:file>
         <cfg:file type="style">/Extrensions/Editors/Counter.css</cfg:file>
         <cfg:file type="script">/Extrensions/Editors/jquery.js</cfg:file>
        <cfg:file type="script">/Extrensions/Editors/Counter.js</cfg:file>
          <cfg:file type="reference">Extrensions.Editors.Counter</cfg:file>
        </cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:dependencies>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
        </cfg:dependencies>
   </cfg:group>
```

What can be the  reason to fail CME loading....why it is not loading js files and css for jquery ui if any one implemented same js in there Extensions please help thanks in advance

Comment: Relevant: [During GUI Extension development, what are the likely causes of a blank user interface with a grey bar](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/223/during-gui-extension-development-what-are-the-likely-causes-of-a-blank-user-int/)

Comment: how to use jquery plugin libraries with Tridion,is there any way please suggest the above link shows prob occurred but not giving solution

Comment: See http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1685/jquery-and-dependencies-for-gui-extensions?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your files in your `<cfg:fileset />` element completely matters.  This means you'll want to put the files that are used by the other resources at the top of your list.  In your example, jQuery UI comes first, then jQuery... I'd imagine this would throw an error so you'd probably want to make sure that jQuery comes first.

Secondly you'll want to make sure you are adding your libraries correctly.  See https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/1689/9 for reference, you'll want to make sure you are dong something like `window.$jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);`.  You'll also want to ensure that you are passing your `$jq` global to the jQuery UI library as well.

If you are still having issues after that, make sure to check the console log... you might get a better clue for debugging the issue.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfg:file type="reference"Extrensions.Editors.Counter</cfg:file>

<cfg:file type="reference">Extrensions.Editors.Counter</cfg:file>
```

Missing the closing tag after reference ?

Second. I wouldn't recommend you to use all those jquery libraries, they make the system slower.

Comment: then how to use the plugin code here is there any thing like bundling and minification in TRdion like in asp.net mvc

Comment: jarnohenneman,Sorry but <cfg:file type="reference">Extrensions.Editors.Counter</cfg:file> is not issue may be i  pasted wrong text now evry thing is right

Comment: @Pankaj786 bundling and minification is automatically done for all the files in your fileset. But I think what Jarno ment was that you are adding a very heavy library (JQuery and JQuery UI) to your extension and you might want to consider not ding that. I'll add a comment about that to your main question, so you can edit the question and add the answer in there.

Comment: I presume the typo is 'known' /Extrensions/ should it not be /Extensions/